# Frequency of element in linked list

Tags: java

I am having a linke list of type point i want to count the frequency of a particular point

**Code**

```
     LinkedList<Point> refernce = new LinkedList<>();
      Point neworigin = new Point();
public void distancecalculator(char [][]problem ,LinkedList<Point> refernce) {

  //Somewhere in my code
         for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
         {

              int a = reference.x + x[i];   // x={ 0 , 0 ,1 , -1}

              int b = reference.y + y[i];    // y ={ 1, -1 , 0 ,0}

              neworigin.x = a;
             neworigin.y = b;
            reference.add(neworigin)
        if(Collections.frequency(refernce, neworigin) < 6)
        {
                   //End the that thread
        }
   else
      {
           solver s = new solver(newproblerm , refernce );

                          som =  new Thread(s);
                          som.start();
       }
```

}
}

**error:**

```
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Exception in thread "Thread-742" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.LinkedList$ListItr.next(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.Collections.frequency(Unknown Source)
```

Upadted it 
.Please help me.

Comment: You need to include what *exception* was thrown. Not just part of the stack trace.

Comment: Add code and whole stacktrace please!

Comment: This is either a bug in the implementation of `LinkedList` or you used it in a wrong way (e.g. from multiple threads - `LinkedList` is not synchronized). Post an [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). And your Java version.

Comment: @icza you are right i have updated it please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using your `LinkedList` from multiple threads. The [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) of `LinkedList` clearly states (in bold) that:

> **Note that this implementation is not synchronized.** If multiple threads access a linked list concurrently, and at least one of the threads modifies the list structurally, it must be synchronized externally.

Your thread name "scares" me:

> Exception in thread "Thread-**742**" java.lang.NullPointerException

It looks you have *many* (hundreds?) of threads. You access `LinkedList` concurrently and chances are high that its internal state gets corrupted.

Then `Collections.frequency()` tries to go over the list using its iterator which hits a `null` value in its implementation probably due to `LinkedList` being corrupted.

Don't use the `LinkedList` from multiple threads without proper synchronization.

Comment: will you suggest me some good approach for this

Comment: As noted and quoted: don't use the `LinkedList` from multiple threads without proper synchronization.

Comment: is arraylist will be a good choice

Comment: Please read the javadoc of [`ArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html). It also states the same: "not synchronized".

Comment: what collection should i used?

Comment: I think you should think over your overall program. I can't advise on what you should use because I don't know your original problem/task.